# How to find and replace more complex in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, replace, visual-studio-2022

I often find myself in situations where a simple find and replace doesn't quite cut it. For example I want to use find and replace to turn this code

```cs
Method(typeof(TypeA));
Method(typeof(TypeB));
Method(typeof(TypeC));
Method(typeof(TypeD));
```

into this

```cs
Method<TypeA>();
Method<TypeB>();
Method<TypeC>();
Method<TypeD>();
```

These lines are spread out across many .cs files.

I can replace `Method(typeof(` with `Method<`, but I don't want to replace `));` with `>();`, because that would mess up a lot of other parts of the code.

Is there a way to do something like replacing `Method(typeof(*));` with `Method<*>();`?

Could this be done? Do I need a plugin?

Comment: Does Visual Studio support regex with capture groups? (never used VS). If so, something like replace:`Method\(typeof\((*?)\)\)`  with: `Method<\1>()` would probably work

Comment: Looking in documentation it seems that VS supports capture groups, when I put `(*?)` in the search field I get error saying the expression is malformed. Maybe I need some more help here. To me Regex might as well be magic.

Comment: Doing 4 distinct replaces should work though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! ole morud mentioned capture groups which helped me find VS documentation and it worked. The syntax is a bit different from what he commented though.

Find: `Method\(typeof\((\w+)\)\)`

Replace:  `Method<$1>()`

To be clear. I have no idea why it is `\w+` or why the replace doesn't need to be escaped. Regex is an alien language to me.

[Documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#capture-groups-and-replacement-patterns)